# java.lang.SecurityException: Specified package "package name" under uid -1 but it is not in Android 13

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-settings

I'm using `Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS` in order to request when the user does not grant permission in purpose.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getActivity().getPackageName(), null);
intent.setData(uri);
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

The code works well only under android 13. If i run this code in Android 13, It happens an exception.

```
 "Bad call made by uid 1000. Package "package name" does not belong to uid -1.
noteOperation
java.lang.SecurityException: Specified package "package name" under uid -1 but it is not
at com.android.server.appop.AppOpsService.verifyAndGetBypass(AppOpsService.java:4858)
at com.android.server.appop.AppOpsService.noteOperationUnchecked(AppOpsService.java:3586)
at com.android.server.appop.AppOpsService.noteOperationImpl(AppOpsService.java:3574)
at com.android.server.appop.AppOpsService.-$$Nest$mnoteOperationImpl(Unknown Source:0)
at com.android.server.appop.AppOpsService$CheckOpsDelegateDispatcher.lambda$noteOperation$4(AppOpsService.java:7928)
at com.android.server.appop.AppOpsService$CheckOpsDelegateDispatcher.$r8$lambda$oOwUoG55BBmJ6yiwhp3OAq3tQ30(Unknown Source:0)
at com.android.server.appop.AppOpsService$CheckOpsDelegateDispatcher$$ExternalSyntheticLambda4.apply(Unknown Source:32)
at com.android.server.policy.AppOpsPolicy.noteOperation(AppOpsPolicy.java:225)
at com.android.server.appop.AppOpsService$CheckOpsDelegateDispatcher.noteOperation(AppOpsService.java:7926)
at com.android.server.appop.AppOpsService.noteOperation(AppOpsService.java:3558)
at com.android.internal.app.IAppOpsService$Stub.onTransact(IAppOpsService.java:486)
at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1316)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1280)"
```

I already set `android:exported="true"` in AndroidManifest.xml.
I don't know why the error happens. 
I hope someone tells me about the exception.

Comment: Meet the same error. Have you found a root cause?

Comment: Not yet :( Someone posted this issue on Google Issue tracker. but they ignored it..

Comment: Are there any updates?

Comment: I got the same error. It seems that might have happened for security reasons that may not compile with android 13 or above.

Comment: @CodingBruceLee Where's the link to the issue tracker post?